# Is the word "shun" the right one to be used in this context?

Tags: word-usage

I read an article which was titled as:

Fans shun AR Rahman's Marvel Anthem, deem it cringeworthy

I'm still pondering over which context has the verb shun been used in here? I think it means "to dislike" here. But it means "to avoid from" as per the most of dictionaries. So, I wanted to ask if it is the right usage of the verb.

Comment: You are correct on both counts. I *think* it means "Fans are [not going to the theaters to see] the movie."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it means simply "avoid" or "do not attend". Disliking it is implied, but not explicitly part of the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, there isn't a huge distinction. Either way, it means that the fans disapprove of the new movie. They avoid it, too, I suppose, but if asked for a definition, one could say the "disassociated themselves from it", less literally.

Point is, you're right, basically. That is what the article is generally trying to convey.